# webshpere to tomcat migration

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Zlr.png)I am trying to migrate an application from WebSphere to Tomcat.The service i have implements ServiceLifecycle(from javax.xml.rpc.server).

when i run it on Tomcat it gives me ClassCastException for Servlet: cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet

-i have added the required jars.

-i have included it the deployement assembly as well.

-i tried including and without including the jars in WEB-INF/lib

Could anyone please provide any info on how to overcome this?

Comment: can you please provide the stack trace of the error you are getting

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Zlr.png

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0Zlr.png

Comment: Whatever it can't cast to Serlet, does it implement Servlet interface?

Comment: no, it implements ServiceLifecycle from from javax.xml.rpc.server